# Wordpress wp_mail temporarily save attachments and delete after email sent

Tags: php, wordpress

Using wp_mail() to handle email and attachments. I'll prefer if the uploaded attachments are temporarily stored and the deleted after email is sent. Currently, the uploads/attachments get saved on the server. How to prevent this?

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'Save' ] ) ) {

function my_custom_email_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$files = $_FILES[ 'my_files' ];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

$attachments = array();

foreach ( $files['name'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $files[ 'name' ][ $key ] ) {
        $file = array(
            'name'     => $files[ 'name' ][ $key ],
            'type'     => $files[ 'type' ][ $key ],
            'tmp_name' => $files[ 'tmp_name' ][ $key ],
            'error'    => $files[ 'error' ][ $key ],
            'size'     => $files[ 'size' ][ $key ]
        );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload(
            $file,
            $upload_overrides
        );
        $attachments[] = $movefile[ 'file' ];
    }
}

$to        = 'exampleadmin@gmail.com';
$subject   = 'Contact Us';
$message   = 'Haiii';
$headers[] = 'From: ' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . ' <fromid@gmail.com>';

add_filter(
    'wp_mail_content_type',
    'my_custom_email_content_type'
);
$wp_mail_return = wp_mail(
    $to,
    $subject,
    $message,
    $headers,
    $attachments
);
if( $wp_mail_return ) {
    echo 'Mail send';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
remove_filter(
    'wp_mail_content_type',
    'my_custom_email_content_type'
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you care if it sends successfully or not?

If not, then just do this:

```
if( $wp_mail_return ) {
    echo 'Mail send';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}

// Loops over the attachments (per your array), and removes the file
foreach ( (array)$attachments AS $file ) {
    unlink( $file );
}
```

If you only want this done if it's sent successfully, just move it inside your if condition:

```
if( $wp_mail_return ) {
    echo 'Mail send';
    // Loops over the attachments (per your array), and removes the file
    foreach ( (array)$attachments AS $file ) {
        unlink( $file );
    }
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Comment: doesn't unlink just delet the filename? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It does.  However, I don't think there's a post associated with the files, based on docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload